# How to take a string from JSON in Angular

Tags: php, json, angular, api, local-storage

So I basically trying to set a token on my localStorage. I make a request to my API in PHP and this is the code:

```
login() {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      "usuario":"juanma",
      "password":"1234"});
    console.log(body);
    const params = new HttpParams();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.http.post<AuthResponse>("http://localhost:8000/login", body, {'headers':headers,'params':params})
      .subscribe(data => localStorage.setItem('token', data.token.toString()));

  }
```

I actually get the token, I even can see it on the console.log (not appears on the code right now, but I tried it and it does appear).

AuthResponse is a model I created that replicates the JSON return from the post method.

However Im not being able to set the token like a string on localStorage, and I get this:

[image]

I'm really lost with this. If anyone can help, I'll be thankfull!

EDIT: Added screenshot of the console.log(data.token) inside the subscribe:
[image]

EDIT 2: Now I get the token right! Problem is that I need to do the method 2 times in order to make it work.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the first time I made the method, it gives the 'undefined' value.

Comment: And for http.post you don't need JSON.stringify. You can add the JSON object directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace your `data.token.toString()` to `data.token.token`

```
login() {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      "usuario":"juanma",
      "password":"1234"});
    console.log(body);
    const params = new HttpParams();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.http.post<AuthResponse>("http://localhost:8000/login", body, {'headers':headers,'params':params})
      .subscribe(data => localStorage.setItem('token', data.token.token));

  }
```

Comment: I does works! However, instead of setting just the value of the token, it sets all the JSON. 

Instead of this (what I get now):
{"token":"...."}
I need to get this:
(value of token)

Comment: I updated my answer, you should be good with data.token then only

Comment: Same error as stated in the question. The localStorage is set to '[object Object]'.

Comment: Show a console.log(data.token) inside the subscribe please

Comment: Added the screenshot of the console.log(data.token)

Comment: I updated my answer again based on your console.log, you need to set data.token.token

Comment: Worked, but I need to do it 2 times in order to set the value. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you need to do 2 times? Please elaborate

Comment: Means that I need to click the login buttom on my HTML for it to work.
First time it gives the undefined thing, and second time it gives the correct token. You can see it as it's stated on the console log on the new screenshot.

Comment: That has nothing to do with localStorage, rather an issue with your API. Are you sure you get a response the first time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251819/discussion-between-jmcamacho7-and-idontwearstring).